# Mock void Method That Sets Private Setter in Implementations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, moq

I have an interface that looks like this...

```
public interface ITempFileNameBuilder
{
    string DirectoryPath { get; }

    string FileName { get; }

    void GenerateNewFileName();
}
```

... and I want to mock the `GenerateNewFileName` method so that it sets the `FileName` property to something new. I know this is an odd request because obviously there is no `set` defined in the interface because it's declared as `private set;` in the two implementations. I did that so you **must** call `GenerateNewFileName` to set the `FileName` property to something new.

Is this possible?

### Edit

Here is the unit of work I'm trying to test.

```
public void StartRecording(string claimNo, string ip_no, string ip_name, IWaveIn input, Stream writer)
{
    if (this.IsRecording)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (_input != null)
    {
        _input.Dispose();
    }
    _input = input;

    _input.WaveFormat = _waveFormat;
    _input.DataAvailable += (s, args) =>
    {
        _writer.Write(args.Buffer, 0, args.BytesRecorded);
        byte[] buffer = args.Buffer;
        for (int index = 0; index < args.BytesRecorded; index += 2)
        {
            short sample = (short)((buffer[index + 1] << 8) | buffer[index + 0]);
            float sample32 = sample / 32768f;
            _aggregator.Add(sample32);
        }

        OnDataAvailable(args);
    };
    _input.RecordingStopped += (s, args) =>
    {
        _input.Dispose();
        _writer.Dispose();

        OnRecordingStopped(args);
    };

    if (this.CurrentRecording != null)
    {
        _tempFileNameBuilder.GenerateNewFileName();
    }

    this.Recordings.Add(new RecordingTrack(claimNo, ip_no, ip_name,
        _tempFileNameBuilder.FileName,
        _recordingDeployer,
        _recordingCompressor));
    if (this.MicrophoneLevel == default(float))
    {
        this.MicrophoneLevel = .75f;
    }

    _aggregator.Reset();
    _writer = writer;

    _input.StartRecording();
    this.IsRecording = true;
}
```

And the goal of this unit test is to ensure that the `FileName` of the `CurrentRecording` and `LastRecording` are in fact different. It's a regression test based on a bug we found earlier. The bug was happening because the `FileName` property on the `RecordingTrack` was not being **set** but rather was just returning the current `FileName` from the `ITempFileNameBuilder` instance and so the idea is to ensure that `GenerateNewFileName` was called **and** ensure that the **set** for the `TempFileName` on the recording track was called.

However, the **set** on the `TempFileName` on the `RecordingTrack` is private too, it's done in the constructor, so maybe this isn't really a unit test and more so an integration test?

Comment: Why don't you ditch the property and have the method return the file name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mocking the *interface*, not the implementation. So you should care about how the caller interacts with this. If you expect them to call `GenerateNewFileName()` and then access `FileName`, just expect those two calls and give back the appropriate results (where the "generated" filename can just be anything).

There's no "field" to set here - you're *just* talking about an API.

Of course, you could easily create a *fake* instead of a mock, and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight Jon. I'm really trying to learn this testing concept but I get myself confused a lot. I wonder if I'm just trying to test too much at once most of the time? It's really hard for me to know *how far* to go when building a unit test. Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: @BigM: It's hard to know whether you're trying to test too much based on what you've shown so far, I'm afraid... but testing in general is quite a fine balance (how big the tests should be, how to use test doubles etc).

Comment: Jon, I've edited my question to give you some more background, if you're **not too busy** I would really appreciate your guidance, it's humbling to even get an answer from you friend.

Comment: @BigM: As Trevor Pilley says, it sounds like *really* the problem is that your temporary filename builder isn't exposing the most appropriate API. If you changed it so that the method returns the file name, it'll be much harder to accidentally reuse the existing name.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I appreciate it. Take care of yourself friend!

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, you need to use an explicit private field instead of the implicitly-generated one in the property. You'll need to make sure that implementations define the `get` method for the `FileName` property in terms of that private field.